# Google Sheets count columns in a merge

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-named-ranges

Is there a formula function in Google Sheets to count the number of columns in a merge? I could assign a named range to the merge to make it easier....

For instance: see the highlighted merged cells here, gives 13 columns:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question with an image to better explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Use the range object's [`getMergedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getMergedRanges()) method. Note that it returns an array of Ranges, so if testing a single cell, be sure to `[0]` -grab the first range returned. Demo with G3 as the cell to test, and getNumColumns() used to detect merge width, per your example. Run it and choose View→Logs to see what it found.

```
function getCellMergeRange() {
  var testSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(),
      testRange = testSheet.getRange("G3"),
      mergeRange = testRange.getMergedRanges()[0];
  Logger.log("Merged Range is "+mergeRange.getA1Notation()+", containing "+(mergeRange.getNumColumns()*mergeRange.getNumRows())+" cells.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!.................